# Increase the amount of items in the Run MRU list

Tags: windows, registry

I'm trying to increase the number of items shown in the Run MRU list.
The registry key in question is

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU
```

The relevant value is MRUList.
From what I've seen, the maximum is 26, the values are a-z.

I've tried adding values with symbols and numbers for the name (e.g. 1, #, +), and adding them to MRUList value, to no avail.

Any ideas?

(using an external launcher program is out of the question)

Comment: "MRU" stands for "most recently used." Windows consults the `RunMRU` key in the Registry to build the program selection list for the Run dialog box (which can be opened by holding down the [Windows logo key](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts) and then pressing the **R** key).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the limit is fixed and you can't use more than 26 entries. You'll have to use another way like an external program - so why is this a bad idea for you? I'm sure there are launchers you can even plug in the start menu near the run command and that'll have almost the same look-and-feel - and if not, you can always code your own launcher.